# Antd table selectedRowKeys returns undefined when selecting a default check and change page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have an Ant Design table component with a checkbox to check the selected values. Now I want to pass a default state that would check the selected values that was being checked already whenever the table was closed since I put it in the modal. I want to achieve an Ant Design table that would check and save the checked values from my state for further usage.

Here is my Full code:

```
const rowSelection = {
  selections: [
    Table.SELECTION_NONE,  
  ],
  getCheckboxProps: (record) => ({
    id: record.id,
  }),
  
};

const columns = [
    {
      title: "Document ID",
      dataIndex: "id",
      key: "id",
      defaultSortOrder: "descend",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.id - b.id,
    },
    {
      title: "Subject",
      dataIndex: "subject",
      key: "subject",
      width: "25%",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.subject.length - b.subject.length,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
    {
      title: "Title",
      dataIndex: "title",
      key: "title",
      width: "25%",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.title.length - b.title.length,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
    {
      title: "Document Type",
      dataIndex: "doc_type",
      key: "doc_type",
      render: (text, record) =>
        record.doc_type && record.doc_type.name ? record.doc_type.name : null,
    },
    {
      title: "File Type",
      dataIndex: "file_type",
      key: "file_type",
      render: (text, record) =>
        record.file_type && record.file_type.name
          ? record.file_type.name
          : null,
    },
    {
      title: "Public",
      dataIndex: "is_public",
      key: "is_public",
      align: "center",
      render: (text, record) =>
        record.ispublic ? (
          <CheckCircleFilled style={{ color: "#28a745" }} />
        ) : (
          <CloseCircleFilled style={{ color: "#dc3545" }} />
        ),
    },
    {
      title: "Date Created",
      dataIndex: "created_at",
      key: "created_at",
      render: (text, record) => dateFormatter(new Date(record.created_at)),
    },
  ];

  const dateFormatter = (date) => {
    const dd = (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getDate();
    const MM = (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" : "") + (date.getMonth() + 1);
    const yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    // create the format you want
    // return (yyyy + "/" + MM + "/" + dd);
    return MM + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
  };

const [selectAlready, setSelectAlready] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(attachmentLists && attachmentLists.length != 0) {
      const documentIds = map(attachmentLists,'id');
      if(documentIds.length != 0) {
        setAlreadySelectedRows(documentIds);        
      }      
    }
  }, [attachmentLists])

<Table
  rowKey={(record) => record.id}
  rowSelection={{
    type: "checkbox",
    selectedRowKeys: selectAlready,
    onChange: (keys, selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
      setSelectAlready(keys);
      setSelectedDocuments(selectedRowKeys);
    },
    preserveSelectedRowKeys: true,
    ...rowSelection,
  }}
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  pagination={{
    pageSize: 10,
    showSizeChanger: false,
    total: pageTotalSize,
    position: ["bottomLeft"],
  }}
  loading={loading}
  onChange={(pagination, filters, sorter) => handleTableChange(pagination)}
/>;
```

Now my problem is, whenever the `useEffect` `alreadySelectedRows` was populate, it will select `selectedRowKeys` the rows that was being selected already based on the provided ID's, but when I go switch to another page, the data will return some undefined values and will not catch the other values that was already being selected. The main problem is `selectedRowKeys` returns undefined from previous page table in array.